# derived automorphisms of K3 surfaces of picard rank one

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, derived-categories

I am aware of work of Bayer-Bridgeland, which describes G=Aut(D(K3)) for a K3 of Picard rank one. Is it possible to use their result to give an explicit presentation of G, in terms of generators and relations?
Actually, I am only interested in the generic quartic surface case.